# Issues installing meteor exe windows

Tags: windows, meteor, installation

on my old system i was able install meteor with the exe and it worked fine now im getting this error and im not sure where to go from here

seems like the processing path is too long but thats self generated

Downloading initial Meteor files...
100 ###########################################################################
Download complete (34 MB)
Extracting files to C:\Users\sprigs\AppData\Local.meteor
................................................................................
....
Error processing path: C:\Users\sprigs\AppData\Local.meteor~\packages\less\4bf6154c28\plugin.compileLess.os\npm\compileLess\plugin\node_modules\less\node_modules\request\node_modules\form-data\node_modules\combined-stream\node_modules\delayedstream\test\integration\test-delayed-http-upload.js

Deleting directory: C:\Users\sprigs\AppData\Local.meteor~

Unexpected exception: System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
   at System.IO.Path.SafeSetStackPointerValue(Char* buffer, Int32 index, Char value)
   at System.IO.Path.NormalizePathFast(String path, Boolean fullCheck)
   at System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(String path)
   at LaunchMeteor.Program.ExtractTgz(Stream stream, String directory, Func`2 transform)
   at LaunchMeteor.Program.BootstrapWarehouse(String warehouse)
   at LaunchMeteor.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: not sure about the error but you can install using this also,try this http://www.getinstacode.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a reply from stephen darnell and he gave me this answer

You appear to be using an old version of LaunchMeteor.exe, please check you have the latest.

You can check what version you have by right clicking on the .exe from Windows explorer, selecting Properties, then the Details tab. The file version should be 0.3.1.0.

The problem is that Meteor contains some very long paths and when these are added to your %LOCALAPPDATA% path they can get too long for some of the Windows APIs.  Although I had taken some steps to mitigate this in previous releases, recent release just push it that bit further. So I changed the APIs that LaunchMeteor.exe uses to extract the bootstrap package, and now it should be just limited by your filesystem (for NTFS the limit is around 32K).

i did have an older version of it which is weird because i re downloaded it but if anyone comes across this